# Change class type for field

Tags: java, class, field

I'm required to do the below task for a beginner tutorial on classes.

```
1) Create a class called User.
  a) Add fields for name, age, and location.
  b) Add a method called toString.
2) In the book class:
  a) Change the author field to be of type User.
  b) Modify the toString method to include the author's name.
```

Below is my code

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public String location;
    public String author;

    public String toString() {
        String description1 = "Name:" + name + " Age:"+ age + " Location:" + location + " Reading:" + author; 
        return description1;
    }

}

public class Book {

    public String title;
    public String author;
    public int numPages;
    public int isbn;

    public Book(String title, String author, int numPages, int isbn){
        this.title = title;
        this.author =  author;
        this.numPages = numPages;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
        return description;
    }       
}
```

I'm not sure how to change the author field to be of type User. Looking at other tutorials, I can't seem to find an answer to something which seems very basic to me :/

Any advice?

Comment: Well look at where you're declaring the `author` field. Which part of the declaration is the type of the field? Find it, and change it to `User`... then look at what else breaks (like assigning a value from the constructor when the incoming value is a `String`). It's not clear what the problem is here - which bit of the task is causing you a conceptual issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly? It seems like I'm declaring author to be in both types, but I have a feeling I need to make a change only in the book class, since it told me to modify it. Do I just remove `author` from the book class then?

Comment: No, you don't remove it - you change its type, just like the instructions say. Find the `author` field in the `Book` class, and change its type to `User`. As a *separate* matter, it's not clear why you've got an `author` field in the `User` class at all. (That should be removed - a user doesn't have an author...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
public String author;
```

You would use

```
public User author;
```

So your constructor changes to

```
public Book(String title, User author, int numPages, int isbn){
    this.title = title;
    this.author =  author;
    this.numPages = numPages;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
```

And instead of

```
public String toString() {
    String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
    return description;
}
```

You would use

```
public String toString() {
    String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author.name + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
    return description;
}
```

Comment: changin constructors argument also required

Comment: Yes, noticed that just as I posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in class `Book` change `public String author;` to `private User author;` and also new `toString()` will look like:

```
public String toString() {
    String description = "Title:" + title + "Author"+ author.getName() + "Num. of pages" + numPages + "ISBN" + isbn; 
    return description;
}
```

and constructor should also be changed into:

```
public Book(String title, User author, int numPages, int isbn){
```